# How to loop over an object in neo4j using cypher

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

Hi i am using nodejs with neo4j-driver and i create relations like this (USER-[ values from the object ]->SUBREDDIT)

Username is predefined so this isn't a problem but the subreddit name and values of relations is inside the object.

The object is really huge so i would prefer use some cypher magic to loop over this object and create relations, bad i have no idea how to do it.

I am also wondering if this is good approach to do that or if it is more efficient to just loop over this object in JavaScript and make more queries

I am trying to make write query, names of objects  (like '63') are meaningless, the name of target node is in sub property, rest of the are relation properties

```
'62': {
  n: 1,
  ups: 15.730142943532986,
  gilded: 0,
  upvote_ratio: 0.9253025260901756,
  num_comments: 2.7759075782705267,
  num_crossposts: 0,
  score: 15.730142943532986,
  sub: 'r/aww'
},
'63': {
  n: 2,
  ups: 33.58852601401853,
  gilded: 0,
  upvote_ratio: 1.2799872062537179,
  num_comments: 7.8618886115333115,
  num_crossposts: 0,
  score: 33.58852601401853,
  sub: 'r/FreeKarma4U'
}
```

Comment: You need to present a clear and focused question. Are you trying to import data into a neo4j DB, or to make queries, or both? And what are your use cases? For us to recommend a good data model, you have to tell us what you want to accomplish with the data. Also, it is not clear what all the data means (like, what is the meaning of '63' and 'n', etc.).

Comment: I am trying to make write query, names of objects  (like '63') are meaningless, the name of target node is in sub property, rest of the are relation properties

Comment: What is the purpose of the queries? Can you show the queries? And why do you put all the properties in the relationship? These general tips for how to ask a good question may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an example for you. Tell me if fits with your purposes! :-)

```js
const products = [
  { name: 'apple', price: 30 },
  { name: 'orange', price: 40 },
  { name: 'lemon', price: 50 },
]

const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password))

const main = async () => {
  try {
      await driver.verifyConnectivity()
      console.log('Driver created')
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(`connectivity verification failed. ${error}`)
  }

  const session = driver.session()
  try {
      await session.run(`
    UNWIND $products as product
    CREATE (p: Product)
    SET p += product
    RETURN COLLECT(p) as products
    `,{products})

  } catch (error) {
      console.log(`unable to execute query. ${error}`)
  } finally {
      await session.close()
  }

  await driver.close()
}

main()
```